# What is the proper term for "the boss," chief: Jefe or Hefe?

Tags: traducción, ortografía, inglés

I see both *Hefe* and *Jefe* used all the time to describe "boss, chief" etc. Which is the most common/correct spelling?

Comment: The word "hefe" is not registered neither in the RAE's dictionary nor in the DAMER dictionary. When you say "all the time", could you specify a bit more? Do you read that word in texts from several authors and several countries? Or is it in a specific context? Maybe a specific work (text, translation, adaptation, subtitles, whatever)?

Comment: @Charlie - It looks like a completely understandable mistake.  See for example https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=El%20Hefe.  Maybe you didn't know this, but there are many Spanish speakers in the US who are most comfortable *speaking in Spanish* but *reading and writing in English*.

Comment: @aparente001 I didn't know that, actually. Reminds me of the "Esmarelda" character in _Pulp Fiction_, named like that because English speakers pronounce that word closer to the Spanish name "Esmeralda". I suppose then that "el hefe" would be a expression imitating the Spanish pronunciation for "el jefe" in English texts?

Comment: @Charlie - I don't know about the movie.  I do know that the spelling of names in the US has gotten completely out of control in general.  At any rate, yes, I do think the spelling "hefe" is the result of some understandable confusion on some people's parts -- maybe some Spanish speakers and some non-Spanish speakers.  Here is an example (real life) person: She came to the US to be a nanny (au pair). She hadn't done much schooling in Ecuador.  As an adult in the US she got a GED high school diploma with difficulty.  She still prefers Spanish for talking but can read somewhat better in English.

Comment: Preliminary answer (since the question hasn't yet been reopened): **"*Jefe* is the standard spelling in Spanish. *Hefe* is an anglicised form (much like we get *canyon* from *cañón*) e.g. [El Hefe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Hefe) (musician), [el hefe](https://elhefe.com/chicago-il/) (nightclub)."**

Comment: It is perfectly true that an English speaker hearing the word jefe might well spell it heffay to imitate the sound but without more context (which the OP was asked for) we cannot be sure that this is the explanation for hefe.

Answer (score 3):

[Jefe](https://dle.rae.es/jefe?m=form), as Hefe is not accepted. I believe "hefe" is just jefe misspelled

Comment: Iria, aunque la pregunta es un poco ambigua (y seguramente será cerrada por no ser lo suficientemente clara) tú puedes mejorar/ampliar tu respuesta añadiendo otras formas, formales o coloquiales, de referirse a un jefe (ya que la parte de Jefe vs. Hefe ya la contestas). Por ejemplo, podrías incluir las definiciones de líder, patrón u otras (si te apetece, ya que como digo la pregunta posiblemente será cerrada)

Comment: Iría, I'm going to differ from my compañeros in spite of their greater experience.  I think your answer is concise and on point - +1 from me.

Comment: What you say @aparente001 may be true and Iria may well be correct but at the moment in the absence of the clarification asked for by Charlie we are just speculating. If I heard jefe I would transliterate it as heffay. I would have thought hefe would rhyme with leaf.

Comment: In some southamerican countries, spanish speakers pronounce h at the beginning of the word like a soft j, or as the English h, the same sound that other countries have for j. That's where the confusion comes from. That's why I do believe that 'hefe' is just jefe wrongly typed

Comment: @mdewey - Have you had a chance to glance at the urban dictionary link I provided?  Urban Dictionary isn't just for looking up *palabrotas*.  It can show what people are seeing, for example, on social media, and what misspellings have spread through the culture.  I think the link I provided suggests that some people in the US are using *hefe* as an alternative spelling for *jefe*.

Comment: @aparente001 if the OP comes back and clarifies that the source was North America then we could proceed but at the moment we do not know.

Comment: I disagree with the review comment. This **does** provide an answer to the question.

Comment: https://dle.rae.es/?w=Hefe, it's not in the dictionary. So far, I'm correct. It's not been accepted yet

Comment: @mdewey - Well, the beauty of the review queue system is that individual participants can have different opinions.  In other words, we can agree to disagree.  In my view, the chances that the OP is in the US, or is influenced by spelling problems that occur in the US, is reasonable enough.  I can certainly understand that you might not share this view.  So I won't keep trying to bring you around to my point of view.

Comment: @wimi and Iria - The software reacts to short answers.  If you ever want to avoid having your answer automatically flagged in that way, there is a workaround - add some material to your answer.  For example, you could quote a definition of *jefe*.